# Is there another way I can get the connection string from SQL Server in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im doing my project and Im looking for a solution if I install it on another PC with different "name",so that the SQL Server name and the connection string from my project would be different and for sure there would be errors..

what I want is to set the connection string without copying it on the properties in server explorer in c#.

Comment: So do you want your connection string to always point to the SQL Server running on the same machine?

Comment: @dotnetom yes sir.as it is :D coz i found out that when you changed the name of your PC the Server name of SQL Server will also change as what name you put it there ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you want to do. I always keep database connection string in `Web.config`(or `App.config`) in `ConnectionStrings` tag and, in this case I can change it easy, especially when I deploy the application in production.

Comment: actually sir im doing my installer of my project ..now,i need to set the connection string of my project on what does the SQL server name was..

Comment: Then you should set the connection string using installer wizard. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/446121/Adding-connection-string-during-installation#AddingcustomControl) an example on CodeProject

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to have connection string in configuration file and update it during the program setup (be it install wizard or some script).

However, you can use `.` instead of server name, if you want to access SQL Server running on the same machine.

If you have connection string that accesses default SQL Server instance, it looks something like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

You can change `myServerAddress` to `.` and it will work fine on this machine:

```
Server=.;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

You can do the same with named SQL Server instances. Change

```
Server=myServerAddress\myInstance;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

to

```
Server=.\myInstance;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```